# Blackjack - probability

Tags: probability

I’m working on a programming assignment but I need help with the probability involved. :/
I’m supposed to figure out the chances that the dealer will win in a game of black jack given his initial card, assuming I decide to not “hit” at all. To make things a little easier, I have to assume that every time a card is taken out of the deck, I have the full set of 52 cards, so I don’t have to consider exactly what cards I have left each time a card is used.
I have absolutely no clue how to do this. Probability and statistics are my downfall. I have already spent over 3 hours trying to figure out this alone and am running out of time. Help! Please?

Comment: I don't know a lot about blackjack. What's the point which you want to calculate the probabilities at? You and the dealer have received a card or just the dealer? (Supposing there is no more people than you and the dealer) What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a complex problem (since it's not just one question, you're devising a strategy for a whole rational game). I'll give you an idea of how I would go about trying to make sense of it.

To figure out your chances, you need something called a Probability DensityFunction (which essentially details the probabilities for all the possible outcomes).

Since the results of a Blackjack draw takes on one among a number of distinct possibilities, [the probability of each outcome is discrete](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~lsimon/stat250/sp98/handouts/handout07.pdf).

E.g.

$$P(X=1)=\frac{0}{52 \choose 2}=0$$
$$P(X=4)=\frac{4 \choose 2}{52 \choose 2}=\frac{1}{221}$$
$$...$$
$$P(X=15)=\frac{? \choose 2}{52 \choose 2}=\frac{?}{?}$$
$$...$$
$$P(X=21)=\frac{? \choose 2}{52 \choose 2}=\frac{?}{?}$$

Once you build a probability table for all 21 possible outcomes in a Blackjack games, you can go about doing statistics on it. For example:

The mean value of a card draw is $$\mu = \mathrm{E}(X)=\sum x\times P(X=x)$$

This information is useful with your assumption: If every draw begins with 52 unique cards in the deck, then the expected value of that draw remains the same every time. Let's pick a magic number: $$\mu = 7$$

Now, every time the dealer picks the first card, you can make some probabilistic guesses about his second pick. I don't know how much probability background you have so I'll give you a few examples:

- The value he most likely will pick up is around 7.
- The extreme ends (very low values and very high values) are less likely to come up than the values in the middle.
- It is easy to find his chances of drawing cards in a certain value range (e.g. from 7-9). This technique is called the **Cumulative Distribution Function**. In a nutshell **for this case only**, his chances of picking a card from 7-9 is equal to the sum of the probability of each value: $$P(7\leq X \leq 9)=P(X=7)+P(X=8)+P(X=9)$$

With these tools, especially with the **Cumulative Distribution Function**, you can start making very good educated guesses about the dealer's chances of winning the match, given his first card.

Rationally, an example strategy would be: you would decide to "hit" if your chance of getting in the "sweet zone" is higher than his. But, of course, the game is much more complicated than that. Figure out the rules, then find all the outcomes and their probabilities, then reason from there.

Answer (score 0):

OK, given that you are drawing from an infinite shoe, you only need to consider 13 cards, 4 of which (10, J, Q & K) are the same value. So your chance of drawing one of them is  $\frac{4}{13}$ and the chance of drawing any of the other cards 9 cards is $\frac{1}{13}$.

So, start with the initial 2 card deal for each of you; this can have a value of between 4 (2 twos) and 21 (A & 10 value card). Derive the probability of each score *with and without* an ace.

The rules of blackjack are straightforward - the dealer must stand on 16 or more. So for each 2 hand score of 16+, the hand is over and you can work out the probability that your hand is bigger.

If the dealer has less than 16 then they must draw another card. For each hand between 4 and 15 work out the probability of each score with and without aces again (since they can be either 11 or 1). If the score is 15 or less then you repeat, if it is 16-21 then you multiply by the probability above, over 21 the dealer loses.

Comment: The dealer hits on 16!